# What are the oldest browser versions supported by Oracle JET?

Tags: oracle-jet

I checked [this](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/globalSupport-FAQ.html) and [this](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/products/browser-policy-2859268.html), but they are very confusing.

For exmaple, if want to know what is the oldest version of firefox that is supported by Oracle JET v4.0, is there any easy way to know?

Comment: Firefox on Windows?

Comment: Currently what I am looking for is firefox on linux, but it would be helpful to have information on other commonly used browsers+OS combinations as well(ex firefox on windows, chrome on windows etc)

Comment: And I'm assuming you are talking about a true technical limitation? Because as per your link Oracle, by policy, only supports the latest ESR release